# How can I pass an array resulting from a Perl method by reference?

Tags: perl, reference

Some `XML::LibXML` methods return arrays instead of references to arrays.

Instead of doing this:

```
$self->process_items($xml->findnodes('items/item'));
```

I want to do something like:

```
$self->process_items(\$xml->findnodes('items/item'));
```

So that in `process_items()` I can dereference the original array instead of creating a copy:

```
sub process_items {
    my ($self, $items) = @_;
    foreach my $item (@$items) {
        # do something...
    }
}
```

I can always store the results of `findnodes()` into an array and then pass the array reference to my own method, but let's say I want to try a reduced version of my code. Is that the correct syntax for passing the method results or should I use something different?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Now suppose I want to change `process_items()` to `process_item()` so I can do stuff on each element of the referenced array using a `for` loop. Something like:

```
$self->process_item($_) for ([ $xml->findnodes('items/item') ]);
```

This doesn't work as `process_item()` is executed only once because a single value is passed to the `for` loop (the reference to the array from `findnodes()`). What's the proper way of using `$_` in this case?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether your edit is a new question or  furbishing further details of the original problem. If it is the former, I suggest you post a new question. If it is the latter, then I feel your question needs some rewording.

Comment: @zaid : It was the latter. I have changed the text so it's clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub  do_something {
    (1, 2, 3, 4);
}

print [ do_something ];
```

This give me an array ref.

EDIT:

so, in your case,  that would be:

```
$self->process_items([ $xml->findnodes('items/item') ]);
```

in which case, `$self->process_items` gets an arrayref.  Similarly, if you wanted to make a hashref out of the return value of a function, you would put { and } around the return value.

EDIT 2:

As for your second question, `for()` takes an array, so, instead of doing `for([ my_list ])` you would do `for( @{ [ my_list ] } )`.  `@{}` generates an array from a list.  `${}` produces a scalar from a scalar-ref.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a for against an arrayref because it only sees one thing, the arrayref itself, not the contents. You'll have to pass a reference to each item if you want to work that way, using something like:

```
map {$self->process_item(\$_)} $xml->findnodes('items/item');

sub process_item {
  my $item = shift;
  $item = $$item;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does? Isn't it basically a `foreach ($xml->findnodes('items/item')) { ... }`?